# Python: continues method call hold until configured delay time

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, delay

From different thread/interface my class getting work,my class has to process the work with configured delay time.

```
def getJob(job):

    work = self._getNextWorkToRun(job)
    if work is None:
        return {}
    #proceed to do work
```

`job` sends by different package to this class. I wanted to call `_getNextWorkToRun()` method every five minutes once only. but the job comes every seconds/less than seconds. So I have to wait until 5 minutes to call `_getNextWorkToRun()` once again with new job. Every job has reference (JOB1,JOB2...etc.,) and all the jobs have to complete with the delay of 5 mins.

What is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Read about [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer)

Comment: @stovfl but getJob method calls every seconds, if the first call happened, then the second call should happen after 5 minutes only. If the first job (ex: JOB1) is called then when second job (ex: JOB2) should sent back, again after sometime JOB2 will be sent back to `getJob()` method. so threading.Timer is not possible with this.

Comment: *"but getJob method calls every seconds"*: [Edit] your Question and explain in detail **why**, you didn't need to poll? Using `Timer` you don't need to poll.

Answer (score 0):

below is an example of using threads, jobs will be added anytime to job queue from any other function and a get_job() function will run continuously to monitor jobs and process them on fixed interval until get a stop flag

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time
from random import random

jobs = Queue()  # queue safely used between threads to pass jobs
run_flag = True

def job_feeder():
    for i in range(10):
        # adding a job to jobs queue, job could be anything, here we just add a string for simplicity
        jobs.put(f'job-{i}')  
        print(f'adding job-{i}')
        time.sleep(random())  # simulate adding jobs randomly
    print('job_feeder() finished')

def get_job():
    while run_flag:
        if jobs.qsize():  # check if there is any jobs in queue first
            job = jobs.get()  # getting the job
            print(f'executing {job}')
        time.sleep(3)
    print('get_job finished')

t1 = Thread(target=job_feeder)
t2 = Thread(target=get_job)

t1.start()
t2.start()

# we can make get_job() thread quit anytime by setting run_flag
time.sleep(20)
run_flag = False

# waiting for threads to quit
t1.join()
t2.join()

print('all clear')
```

output:

```
adding job-0
executing job-0
adding job-1
adding job-2
adding job-3
adding job-4
adding job-5
adding job-6
adding job-7
executing job-1
adding job-8
adding job-9
job_feeder() finished
executing job-2
executing job-3
executing job-4
executing job-5
executing job-6
get_job finished
all clear
```

note get_job() processed only 6 jobs because we send quit signal after 20 seconds